# Arithmetic Intensity in Nvidia Architectures

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I am new to GPU programming, and am trying to determine whether a particular product is worth porting to a GPU in the first place.  One major step in the algorithm requires the calculation of a large number of [Frobenius products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) (like a dot product, but on matrices-- an elementwise multiplication followed by summation of the products.)

The data structures are such that I can store everything in global memory of a GPU but not in the shared memory.  My understanding is that GPUs perform best when the arithmetic intensity (floating point operations per byte transferred) is high, and that dot products perform (relatively) poorly in this regard.  I am trying to figure out how poorly, and am confused by some of the details.

To make things concrete, let us assume I have 64x64 matrices of double precision entries.  (They must be double precision.)  Let us assume that the matrices are laid out so that they are aligned correctly, as well.  Clearly, this is too large to store in shared memory even at one block per SM.  So my thought is to "tile" the problem and store a 16x16 tile of each matrix in each block; now I can at least operate on all eight blocks at once, assign a thread to each product, compute the sums in each block, etc.

My questions are:

1)  What exactly is meant by FLOPS/byte?  Or more precisely, in this context, how many FLOPS are required for a double precision multiply?  If the answer is 1, then it seems I'm moving 16 bytes for every operation, which seems terrible.

2)  Is this calculation done in a context of coalesced memory reads?  Does coalescing help me or hurt me?

And the more nebulous question:

3)  Is this even worth doing?

For reference, I have access to a GTX 580 for benchmarking and experimentation, and CUDA 4.2, although I could probably get 5.0 installed if it would help.  And if more recent Nvidia architectures are friendlier in some regard, that would also be useful to know although I may not be able to get access to one.

**UPDATE:**

I am still working through the entire algorithm, but I have strong reason to believe that the matrices can be generated and kept on the GPU in global memory without moving anything ack and forth to the CPU.

I may have to re-examine my assumption that I can ensure coalesced memory access.  Some of the matrices are slices of a four dimensional object; about 3/4 of my matrices will naturally be accessed in an obvious coalesced fashion, while the other 1/4 aren't.  I might solve that by storing the large object twice, but that generates a new question:

4)  Do the coalesced memory guidelines apply to movement from shared memory back into global memory, as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Correct. One (double precision) multiply is one floating point operation, or FLOP. If you need to load both operands from memory, that is 1/16 FLOPS/byte. If however you need the product of *m* matrices with *n* others, you ideally get (*m* * *n*) / (8 * (*m* + *n*)) FLOPS/byte, and for sufficiently large *m* and *n* you have an arithmetically intense problem.

2) Coalesced memory reads help to achieve (close to, like 80% of) the specified memory bandwidth. Assume for now that you can indeed achieve these, the cache on the compute capability 2.0 GTX 580 helps a lot with this.

3) It depends. GPUs also have about 10x the memory bandwidth of CPUs, so even memory bound tasks can be faster.

4) Yes, they do (for the global memory side of the move). Shared memory has different rules to avoid "bank conflicts". However don't bother with that now, as shared memory access is orders of magnitude faster that global memory access, so it's almost only the latter that matters.

The most important factor is: Where do the matrices come from that you need to multiply? If they come from the host and need to be transferred through PCIe, it's a loss and the products should better be computed on the CPU.
If the matrices can be generated on the GPU, that is fine and you will profit from the higher memory bandwidth. If you can compute the dot products on the fly while generating the matrices without ever storing them in off-chip memory, the GPU will shine. Although that will depend on how efficiently the matrices can be computed, the dot product will probably just be a tiny "aftermath" to that. Are you really sure the computation of the products is your most time-consuming step?

Comment: I will update the question to address some of these issues, but can you clarify "off-chip"?  Clearly shared memory is "on-chip."  Clearly anything off the GPU and accessible to the CPU is "off-chip."  What about global memory?

Comment: Global memory is basically what I meant with off-chip. It sometimes comes disguised under different names like "local memory" (which really is global memory with a different addressing scheme). So to include these cases in my general statement, and to emphasize on the need to move data over (slower) chip-to-chip interconnects, I've written "off-chip".

Comment: Okay, that gives me much to think about, and points out where the major difficulties will be in this portion of the algorithm.  I believe the takeaway is that there will be no magic 10x or 100x improvement in this portion because the arithmetic intensity is too ow, but, I should still get performance increases that scale with the card.